# i am not able to get full JSON reply on the phone but the browser is giving me complete reply for google maps transit api

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

just change the time according to UTC to check ...

but i'm getting a incomplete cut version on the mobile app ..

`String archiveQuery ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=RV%20College%20Bus%20Stop,%20Mysore%20Road,Bangalore,Karnataka&destination=Malleswaram,Bangalore,Karanataka,India&sensor=false&departure_time=1353850800&mode=transit&alternatives=true";

```
Log.d("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%",archiveQuery);

       String arch=archiveQuery;
      InputStream in = null;
      String queryResult = "";
      try {
       URL url = new URL(arch); 
       HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
       httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
       httpConn.connect();
       in = httpConn.getInputStream();
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
       ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000000);
       int read = 0;
       int bufSize = 5000000;
       byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
       while(true){
        read = bis.read(buffer);
        if(read==-1){
         break;
        }
        baf.append(buffer, 0, read);
       }
       queryResult = new String(baf.toByteArray());
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.toString();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.toString();
       }
```

try {

```
            JSONObject jObject;
            Log.d("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%",queryResult);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FFFFFFFFFFFFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            jObject = new JSONObject(queryResult);
            JSONArray routes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            String statu  = jObject.getString("status").toString();
            if(statu.equals("OK")){

                int num=routes.length();
                for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
                    {
                JSONArray legs=routes.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("legs");
                JSONArray steps=legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("steps");
                int l=steps.length();
                for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
                    if(steps.getJSONObject(j).getString("travel_mode").toString()!="WALKING")
                        {
                            JSONObject trans=steps.getJSONObject(j).getJSONObject("transit_details");
                            JSONObject line=trans.getJSONObject("line");
                            Log.d("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",line.getString("short_name").toString());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), line.getString("short_name").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             }
                    }}

            else
            {

           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Suggestion not available! Please search" +
                "another placeor search in maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
       }
       catch (JSONException e) {e.toString();}

      `     this is code i am using
```

Comment: if you are using `HttpClient` then change your code using `httpurlconnection ` for open an `inputstream` to get all JSON  on device

Comment: ..i have updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
String res = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
Log.i("JSON content", res);
// Then parse it
```

Comment: i tried this but its still not giving me the complete json reply that i see on the browser just a part of it ..